# How to pass Activity to a service

Tags: android, android-activity, service, param

How do i pass an activity as parameter for a spesific service :

here is the service :

for each 5 seconds i want this action to occure: (for messanger updte)

```
        channel_id = intent.getStringExtra("channelID");
        if (MapWithMarkers.channels_map.get(channel_id).getChannel_messages().size()
                > ChatActivity.last_given_size_of_messages) {
            if (activity != null) {

                ((ChatActivity) activity).updateNewMessagesOnScreen(); // THIS MUST ACCEPT ACTIVITY!!!
            }


        }
```

now i want to call this from the activity that calls the service:

```
public void updateNewMessagesOnScreen() {
    List<MessageItem> messages = MapWithMarkers.channels_map.get(channelId).getChannel_messages();
    int max_size = messages.size();

    for (int i = last_given_size_of_messages; i < max_size; i++) {
        if (messages.get(i).getUser_id().equals("me")) {
            adp.add(new ChatMessage(false, messages.get(i).getText()));
        } else {
            adp.add(new ChatMessage(true, messages.get(i).getText()));
        }
    }
    last_given_size_of_messages = max_size;
}

package com.ap2.demo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.IBinder;

import com.ap2.demo.enumPackage.Constants;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class ChatService extends Service {
    private Timer timer = new Timer();
    String channel_id ="";
    Activity activity = null;
    // Binder given to clients
    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // code to execute when the service is first created
        int x = 10;

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {if (timer != null) {
            timer.cancel();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, int flags, int startid) {

        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                channel_id = intent.getStringExtra("channelID");
                // Check if there are updates here and notify if true
                // new ServerSamples().execute(Constants.SERVER_REQUESTS.GET_SERVERS);
                if (MapWithMarkers.channels_map.get(channel_id).getChannel_messages().size()
                        > ChatActivity.last_given_size_of_messages) {
                    if (activity != null) {
                        ((ChatActivity) activity).updateNewMessagesOnScreen();
                    }


                }


            }
        }, 0, 1000);
        return START_STICKY;
    }


    /**
     * Class used for the client Binder.  Because we know this service always
     * runs in the same process as its clients, we don't need to deal with IPC.
     */
    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        ChatService getService() {
            // Return this instance of LocalService so clients can call public methods
            return ChatService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

        return mBinder;
    }
    /** method for clients */
    public void setActivity (Activity activity, String channel_id) {
        this.activity = activity;
        // Check if there are updates here and notify if true

        if (MapWithMarkers.channels_map.get(channel_id).getChannel_messages().size()
                > ChatActivity.last_given_size_of_messages) {
            if (activity != null) {
                ((ChatActivity) activity).updateNewMessagesOnScreen();
            }
        }
    }

    private void stopService() {
        if (timer != null) timer.cancel();
    }


}
```

in my activity:

```
 @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // Bind to ChatService
        Intent intent = new Intent(ChatActivity.this, ChatService.class);
        bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        // Unbind from the service
        if (mBound) {
            unbindService(mConnection);
            mBound = false;

        }
    }
    /** Defines callbacks for service binding, passed to bindService() */
    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                                       IBinder service) {
            // We've bound to LocalService, cast the IBinder and get LocalService instance
        ChatService.LocalBinder binder = (ChatService.LocalBinder) service;
        chatService = binder.getService();
        chatService.setActivity(ChatActivity.this, channelId);
        mBound = true;

    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
        mBound = false;
    }
};
```

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, but are you tried to call Activity through Intents from your service?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best solution is to use [Bound Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html)

> A bound service is the server in a client-server interface. A bound
>   service allows components (such as activities) to bind to the service,
>   send requests, receive responses, and even perform interprocess
>   communication (IPC). A bound service typically lives only while it
>   serves another application component and does not run in the
>   background indefinitely.

Alternatively you can [send messages through broadcast](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/messages.html)

> You send messages using the MessageApi and attach the following items to the message:
>
> An arbitrary payload (optional) A path that uniquely identifies the
>   message's action Unlike with data items, there is no syncing between
>   the handheld and wearable apps. Messages are a one-way communication
>   mechanism that's good for remote procedure calls (RPC), such as
>   sending a message to the wearable to start an activity.

Comment: tryied that. but was only called once though